# Scientific Algorithms that can produce imagery, pseudocode perhaps?

Tags: math, drawing

I have a client who is based in the field of mathematics. We are developing, amongst other things, a website. I like to create a mock-up of a drawing tool that can produce some imagery in the background based on some scientific algorithms. The intention being that the client, later, may create their own. (They use emacs for everything, great client.)

I'm looking for an answer about where or what to search. Not code specific, pseudocode even, as we can adapt and have not yet settled on a platform.

I'm afraid my mathematics stops at the power of two and some trigonometry. Appreciated if they're are any mathematics related students/academics how could enlighten me? What to search for will be accepted?

Edit: To summarise/clarify, I want to draw pretty pictures (the design perspective). I want them to have some context (i.e. not just for the sake of pretty images but have some explanation available). In essence I would to create a rendering engine which they can draw/code the images and we set the style parameters: line, colour, etc... But to pursue this option I want to experiment myself.

Edit: great responses thanks. The aim is to make something along the lines of http://hascanvas.com/ if anyone is interested.

Thanks
Ross

Comment: 'In the field of mathematics'.  If you give us more information about your clients we might be able to give you better help.  Mathematics is a big field these days, images which might resonate with computational physicists might leave numerical biologists entirely unmoved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Mandelbrot set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set), [Julia sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set), [random graphs](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomGraph.html), [Lorenz attractor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_attractor).

Maybe [minimising energy functions on a sphere](http://www.maths.unsw.edu.au/school/articles/me100.html).

Comment: thanks! last example looks from a distance looks like an opengl tutorial. I like it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite sure that I don't fully understand what you are after, so to provoke you and others into clarifying, I suggest you grab a copy of *Mathematica* and of *Web Mathematica* and knock your clients out with that.

Answer (score 2):

[Mandelbulb](http://www.google.com/images?q=mandelbulb).

Answer (score 1):

Fractals [image: image of the mandelbrot set from wikipedia] with [pseudo code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set#For_programmers).

Comment: I think OP is unlikely to impress clients with one of the most (over-)used images from all of mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at these links:

- https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Curves/
- https://www.nctm.org/classroomresources/
- https://planetmath.org/famouscurves